# Laravel live server won't work with eager loading

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, ardent

I've got some code that has been working fine on my local machine (WAMP, PHP 5.4.3) but not on a production server (CentOS, PHP 5.4.11) and I can't see why, the offending line of code is:

```
$sharedList = SharedList::with('itemList')
                          ->where('unique_url', '=', $uniqueURL)
                          ->first();
```

if I remove the with() eager loading then this runs without issue, if I don't (and I don't need to on my local machine) then I get this:

```
Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::match() 
must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection, instance of 
ItemList given, called in /home/mgc/public_html/test/vendor/laravel/framework
/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php on line 474 and defined 

/home/site/public_html/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsTo.php

line 154: public function match(array $models, Collection $results, $relation)
```

The relevant relationship info from the SharedList model is:

```
class SharedList extends Ardent {

public function itemList()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('ItemList', 'list_id');
}
```

I don't know if this is a capitalisation issue, in the with() method I have tried ItemList, itemlist and itemList.

It could be an Ardent issue, but I have tried replacing `extend Ardent` with `extend Eloquent` to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Your `with('itemList')` is correct, as it should be the name of the function setting up the relationship.  I have a feeling the problem might be with the where clause coming after that.  Try lazy eager loading.

```
$sharedList = SharedList::where('unique_url',$uniqueURL)->get();
$sharedList->load('itemList');
```

Comment: Hi, That throws up the exact same error, I guess it's down to the relationship setup somehow